# ExpressionWrapper inside Annotate is not working in django

Tags: django, python-3.x

```
from django.db.models import F, ExpressionWrapper

resource_list = Resources.objects.filter(active=True, status__id=STATUS_PUBLIC_ID)

resource_list = resource_list.annotate(rank=ExpressionWrapper(
                            similar(keywords, F('title')), output_field=DecimalField()
            )).filter(rank__gt=0).order_by('-rank').distinct()

def similar(a, b):
print(a, b)
return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
```

When i run the code above it gives me an error
"TypeError: 'F' object is not iterable"
Resources is the model i have which has a field title
and similar is a function to check the ratio of similarity between 2 strings

Comment: Can you share the code for similar funciton? Looks like it is expecting an iterable as the second argument.

Comment: The thing is, to the similar function it doesn't pass the value of F('title') it passes it as F(title)